# Visual Studio Unit tests: run initialization code before each test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visualstudio.testtools

I'm using Visual Studio's Test Tools for unit testing. I need some **initialization** code to run **before each test**.

I have a `Setup` class for the initialization code. I already added code to run before each test *run*, using `[AssemblyInitialize]`, but I can't figure out how to do the same on a single test basis.

I tried using the `[TestInitialize]` attribute, but this only applies to tests in the same file as the `[TestInitialize]` method. I would like the initialization code to run automatically for all tests in the assembly, without having to explicitly call it in each and every test file.

```
[TestClass]
public class Setup
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void InitializeTestRun(TestContext context)
    {
        //... code that runs before each test run
    }

    [TestInitialize] //this doesn't work!
    public static void InitializeTest()
    {
        //... code that runs before each test
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no equivalent of `AssemblyInitialize` that runs for every test. I think you would have to base all your classes on a common base class to do that. What do you need to do in the initialisation? There may be another way.

Comment: Basically I'm mocking an Entity Framework context by using in memory dbsets, to avoid actually calling the real database. I'd like a fresh instance of a context for each test, i.e. a clean, empty 'db', so the tests do not interfere with eachother.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a clean way of doing that, all your test files may have to have their own `TestInitialize` method which calls the db initialization.

Comment: Don't know MSTest enough but the following should work (at least it works with other test frameworks): Create a base class DatabaseIntegrationTests with the TestInitialize method. Derive your other Testclasses from that base class.

Comment: @tobsen if you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should work (at least it works with other test frameworks):

- Create a base class DatabaseIntegrationTests with the `TestInitialize` method
- Derive your other Testclasses from that base class

Answer (score 7):

It *[is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)* `[TestInitialize]` but you have the syntax wrong, it doesn't take a context:

```
[TestInitialize]
public static void InitializeTests()
{
    //... code that runs before each test
}
```

Comment: I indeed got the syntax wrong (I will adjust it in the question), but sadly this doesn't solve the problem: TestInitialize does not apply to tests in another file

Comment: is the other file a partial file of the same class? IIRC the InitializeTests will only be run for all the tests of the surrounding class (in your case public class Setup)

Comment: No it isn't. I have many test classes, but only a single Setup class.